# How to increase the badge number when the app is killed (not in BG)? IOS

Tags: ios, badge

I'm able to to manage the update of badge icon when the app is in background but i cant do it when the app is killed.. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no way to do that, badge counter is not supposed to be manipulated like that anyway.

Comment: But eg. Facebook, Gmail... they are able to mange this kind of things.

Comment: Using remote notifications. Not the app itself.

Comment: If you have a server sending push notifications, it can be used to set any badge counter.

Comment: Yes, i have, take a look at my payload: dict = ["APNS": "{\"aps\":{\"content-available\": \"1\", \"badge\":\"1\",\"channel\":\"\(channel)\"}}"]

Comment: ****Solved****
I was passing a String instead of an int

Comment: How whatsapp developer do update the badge count after killing the app ?